# Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to launch the PHP open cart Application in AWS Beanstalk and I got these errors. I need to mention here that I have created my own VPC and security group here.
here are the errors I go while launching the environment.

**Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. Initialization in progress (running for 11 minutes). None of the instances are sending data. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.**

**Stack named 'awseb-e-psmsk5zsxd-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].**

**The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a failed EC2 instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching the environment again.**

[image]

*This is my VPC*

[image]

And also this is my configuration

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue. thank you!